# Сортировка динамической таблицы

Tags: javascript, json, sortable, table

Есть таблица, которая создается динамически от JSON, это значит, что нет постоянных столбцов и значения могут быть разными(числа, строки), помогите, пожалуйста, с решением, Вот такого подгружается таблица после ввода данных.

```
<table id="table">
 <thead>
  <tr class="rowH">
   <th class="thElem" onclick="sort(this)"></th>
   ....
  </tr>
 </head>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="rowClass">
   <input value="Delete" type="checkbox" class="del">
   <td>
    <input type="text"...>
   </td>
   ...
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowClass">
   ...
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка `<input value="Delete" type="checkbox" class="del">`, ибо внутри `<tr>` не допускается использовать сей тег.